# Define Eclipse development target platform based on feature dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2

**Background**

In my RCP application, I have a project that consists of a plugin and a feature, the setup is like this:

```
my.plugin/
  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  plugin.xml
  src/
my.feature/
  feature.xml
```

The plugin contains *unversioned* dependencies towards other bundles (in other features). The feature contains *versioned* dependencies towards other features.

In the end, I will build a RCP application as a feature-based product.

All feature dependencies can be found in a p2 repo hosted by a [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) server (over HTTP).

**Problem**

The above can be built fine using Tycho and the manifest-first approach. Tycho picks up the correct target platform based on the versioned feature dependencies.

When developing, I would like to create a target platform given the specified features by reading the feature versions, so that I know that development is being done against a target platform that is compatible with the specified set of features.

What is a good way to create a target platform based on this feature dependency specification? Ideally, I think I would just like to generate the target platform automatically using the latest compatible versions, just like Tycho does.